# Why are entities from createSelector returning null when tested in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am writing unit tests using Jest/Testing Library.

When I render a component that uses createEntityAdapter method of redux/toolkit, it returns this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

      11 |   companySelectors.selectAll,
      12 |   (selectedCompanyId, entities) => {
    > 13 |     return entities.find((e) => e.id === selectedCompanyId);
         |                                   ^
      14 |   },
      15 | );
```

The code above is part of createSelector's arguments passed in.

Here is the selector:

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from 'src/store';
import { companyAdapter } from './company.slice';

export const companySelectors = companyAdapter.getSelectors<RootState>(
  (state) => state.company,
);

export const getSelectedCompany = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.company.selectedId,
  companySelectors.selectAll,
  (selectedCompanyId, entities) => {
    return entities.find((e) => e.id === selectedCompanyId);
  },
);
```

Here is where the companyAdapter is created:

```
    import { createEntityAdapter, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import { Company } from 'src/types/company';
    import { getAllCashScenarios } from '../cash-scenario/cash-scenario.thunk';
    import {
      getAllCompanies,
      getAuthenticatedCompany,
      getCurrentCompany,
    } from './company.thunk';
    
    export interface CompanyState {
      current: Company;
      selectedId: string;
      cashScenarios: number[];
    }
    
    export const companyAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Company>();
    
    const initialState = companyAdapter.getInitialState({
      current: undefined,
      selectedId:
        typeof window !== 'undefined'
          ? window.localStorage.getItem('companyId')
          : undefined,
      cashScenarios: [],
    } as CompanyState);
    
    export const slice = createSlice({
      name: 'company',
      initialState,
      reducers: {
        selectCompany: (state, action) => {
          state.selectedId = action.payload;
          localStorage.setItem('companyId', state.selectedId);
        },
      },
      extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(getCurrentCompany.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.current = action.payload;
        });
    
        builder.addCase(getAuthenticatedCompany.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.current = action.payload;
          state.selectedId = state.current.id;
          localStorage.setItem('companyId', state.selectedId);
        });
    
        builder.addCase(getAllCompanies.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          companyAdapter.upsertMany(state, action);
        });
    
        builder.addCase(getAllCashScenarios.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.cashScenarios = action.payload.map((p) => p.id);
        });
      },
    });
    
    const { reducer } = slice;
    export default reducer;
    export const companyActions = slice.actions;
```

Given the code above, how can I make sure that individual entities in '`entities`' object is not undefined?

I have passed in a mock state in the Provider when i render the component:

```
const mockState = company: {
    ids: ['1234', '1235'],
    entities: {
      1234: {
        id: '1234',
        name: 'Awesome Company',
        createdDate: '2021-01-01',
        lastUpdated: '2022-01-03',
        dates: ['Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016'],
      }
    },
    selectedId: '1234',
}
```

clearly, `selectedId` and `entities` is defined.

Comment: Hey, did u find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I think I find a reason. In my case I create store, add entities using `adapter.setAll`, but state is still empty:

```js
// test.spec.js

const store = mockStore()

productsAdapter.upsertMany(store.getState().products, [...])


// I expect to receive filled collection, but get initial values
productsAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll(store.getState().products) // []
store.getState().products // { ids: [], entities: {} }
```

But it works in app with extraReducers:

```js
// productsSlice.s

export const productsSlice = createSlice({
  // ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(api.endpoints.products.matchFulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      productsAdapter.setAll(state, payload)
    })
  },
})
```

So the problem is in an immer. There is in `addMatcher` we get an immer wrapper of state and if we change same field into state, it will be updated. If you see source code of `setAll` method (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/entities/sorted_state_adapter.ts#L59), it has mutation operations on state object.

But in test we have a state object with readonly properties (without immer). So when we try to set data, we don't really do anything.

The problem is solved by passing collection as initial state:

```js
// test.spec.js

const store = makeStore({
  [productsSlice.name]: productsAdapter.setAll(
    productsSlice.getInitialState(),
    [...]
  ),
})

// get not empty array as expected
productsAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll(store.getState().products) // [...]
```